# If I mix rum, gin, vodka and scotch whisky, put it in a water bottle, and leave it for a month will it be safe to drink?

Tags: alcohol, mixing

I mixed gin, vodka, rum and scotch whisky together, put it into a water bottle, and left it for about 1 month, would it make me sick If I drank it?

Comment: There are two factors that will change any answer, one is about the shelf-stability of each ingredient, and one is about the shelf-stability of the bottle (preferably in regards to alcohol). Without this information, all anyone here can do is guess.

Comment: You will of course get sick if you drink the mixture like water, right now. Clearly mark the water bottle, draw an attention sign on it.

Comment: There is a drink like that Aunt Roberta. In Poland any drink that is mix of few alcohols and only them is called "Cad"

Comment: You'll definitely get sick, but it won't be because of bacteria.

Answer (score 5):

Gin, vodka, rum and whisky are all distilled spirits, so you'd be essentially mixing up essentially four versions of same thing and get to a different version of the same thing. Individually the alcohol content in these spirits more than high enough to prevent microorganisms from growing when stored for years in a closed container, including the the plastic bottles they're sometimes sold in. When mixed together this will remain true and there's nothing about any normal water bottle that would change this.

Comment: Thr only caveat is that plastic water bottles are made of a thinner and different type of plastic than liquor bottles. It should still be fine after a month but extended storage (3+ months) isn't a great idea.